# How to filter by selected rows in DevExpress ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I want to do something like this

```
grid.ApplyFilter("[Selected] == \'true\'");
```

to apply a filter by selected row in my grid.

The column I want to filter by is

```
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True" VisibleIndex="0" Width="10px">
            <HeaderTemplate>                                                        
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="gvGridView.SelectAllRowsOnPage(this.checked);" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported as the out of box functionality.  However, we have just created a new example showing how this can be done and published it on our  web site.  Here is the link to it:

[How to filter selected / unselected ASPxGridView's DataRows](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E3085)

Answer (score 0):

```
private DataRow SelectRoW()
    {
        DataRow[] objDataRows = null;

            if (gridView1 == null || gridView1.SelectedRowsCount == 0)
            { return null; }//end if
            else
            {
                objDataRows = new DataRow[gridView1.SelectedRowsCount];
                for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.SelectedRowsCount; i++)
                {
                    objDataRows[i] = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[i]);
                }//end for

                gridView1.BeginSort();
                try
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in objDataRows)
                    {
                        return row;//return selected row.
                    }//end foreach
                }//end try
                finally
                {
                    objDataRows = null;
                    gridView1.EndSort();
                }//end finally


            }//end else

        return null;
    }//end SelectRoW
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add some words or explanation to your answer?